# How to remove a specific block from right column which must be shown on rest of the pages?

Tags: layout, magento

I had created a static block containing images aligned vertically then I added an xml block for calling it in the right column in catalog.xml.
Now it is showing that block on all pages .
BUt I dont want just this specific block to be displayed on detail page . So how can I restrict it not to be shown on detail page while showing on rest of the pages.
I did tried to remove it by this:

```
<remove name="right.info" />
```

And this is the block I'm calling:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="banners">
    <block type="cms/block" name="right.info">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>right_logos</block_id></action>
    </block>
</block>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<reference name="banners">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.info</name></action>
</reference>
```